# Order ADODB Recordset

Tags: vb6, adodb

H there, I need to merge and order  3 recordset.
I am  able to merge the 3 recordset but I cannot use the sort method on the result recordset.

Can you help me? How can I sort a recordset manually?

Comment: By merging you mean .addnew'ing rs2 and rs3 to rs1? what happens when you try to sort rs1? are they disconnected recordsets?

Comment: The 3 recordset are the result of a query on 3 different LDAP server. I need to marge the 3 recordsed and the sort by CN field. I do not know why, but If I call the sort method, vb return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **UNION ALL** to preserve the order of the record sets that you select.

Example:

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3 from table2
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3 from table3
```

just make sure that columns are all of the same type, otherwise you might get an exception.

Comment: I am queryng and LDAp taht not support UNION statement

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do UNION SQL queries on this data?
What about doing

*Query1* **UNION** *Query2* **UNION** *Query3* **ORDER BY**  *column1*, *column2*